# Is mysql_close required on connection failure?

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a code snippet which connects to a MySQL database like this (not directly from code so there might be typos):

```
m_connectionHandler = mysql_init(NULL);
if (m_connectionHandler == NULL)
{
  // MySQL initialization failed
  return;
}

MYSQL *tmp = mysql_real_connect(m_connectionHandler,
                                m_hostname,
                                m_username,
                                m_password,
                                m_dbName,
                                m_port,
                                NULL,
                                m_flags);
if (tmp == NULL)
{
  // Connect failed
  mysql_close(m_connectionHandler);
  return;
}
```

My question is if `mysql_close` (in the second if clause `tmp == NULL`), in the case when `mysql_real_connect` returns NULL, is required, or if `mysql_real_connect` frees the connection handler for me upon failure?

The documentation does state that what you get from `mysql_init` should be freed by `mysql_close`, but there are indications that it's already freed by `mysql_real_connect` upon failure.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to `mysql_init(NULL)` allocates memory. Regardless of whether you're able to really connect to the server, you've still allocated memory, so you need to free it with `mysql_close`, which not only closes connections but also releases memory. I see no indication in the documentation that `mysql_real_connect` would free the memory itself.

Comment: I finally checked through the source and it appears that they do some free'ing of memory at the bottom of `mysql_real_connect`, but it is not at all clear that it does everything that `mysql_close` does, so I'll accept this answer.